# Shifting Features using Arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy

I am looking to shift some geometric features using ArcPy. However, I receive the following error message each time that I run the script. What is the issue?

```
import arcpy
def shift_features (in_features):  
...  with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ['SHAPE@XY','XShift',YShift']) as cursor:  
...       for row in cursor:  
...           cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + (row[1] or 0), 
...                              row[0][1] + (row[2] or 0)]])  
...  return
...
```

When then I put :

```
shape=r'E:\Yael\All Sorts\Testing\MovingPolygon.shp'
shift_features(shape)
```

(where shape contains fields name XShift, YShift)

I keep getting :

> Parsing error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You're missing a single quote around `YShift`

Comment: @pbreach 

I've added the single quote, but now I am receiving the following error.

`Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in shift_features
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row`

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you're basing your code off of [this ArcPy Café recipe](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/shifting-features/).)

When you call `cursor.updateRow`, you need to pass back to it a parameter: a list of values the same length as the list of `row` that it would be working with. So, for example...

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, ['FIELD', 'FOO', BAR']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row                # prints a list of 3 values -- ['a', 'b', 'c']
        row[0] = 'd'             # changes element 0 of list
        print row                # ['d', 'b', 'c']
        cursor.updateRow(row)    # passes ['d', 'b', 'c']
```

I only *changed* the value of `FIELD`, but also had to send back values for `FOO` and `BAR`. I could also shorten it:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, ['FIELD', 'FOO', BAR']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow(['d', 'b', 'c'])    # will work
```

But passing fewer values in the list won't work:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, ['FIELD', 'FOO', BAR']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow(['d'])    # will fail
```

(It will similarly break if I pass *too many* values -- the number of elements in the list needs to match the number of fields called by the `UpdateCursor`.)

---

So for your specific situation, you need to pass back values for `SHAPE@XY`, `XShift`, and `YShift`. Right now, it's only getting `SHAPE@XY` (which is all the original snippet recipe was working with).

Try:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ['SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow([[row[0][0] + (row[1] or 0),
                           row[0][1] + (row[2] or 0)]], row[1], row[2])
```